# Can someone help me with this linked list? C++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list, definition

I have an object oriented exam tomorrow and I'm still stuck with linked lists. For some reason I cant quite understand how they work or how to implement them properly. I've watched a lot of videos and tutorials but it still is quite complex. I always get an error which prints nothing to the console, just a blank black page. Can someone tell em what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string name;
    int number;
    node* next;
};
struct node* head = 0;

class Employees
{
private:
    node* head, * tail;
public:
    Employees()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void addToList(string Name, int Num)
    {
        node* n = new node;
        n->name = Name;
        n->number = Num;
        n->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = n;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    void PrintAll()
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            node* current;
            while (current != NULL)
            {
                cout << current->name << "\t";
                cout << current->number;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employees a;
    a.addToList("Robert", 54);
    a.addToList("Manny", 77);

    a.PrintAll();

}
```

Comment: ***Can someone tell em what am I doing wrong?*** Not using your debugger to figure out how your code failing to work as you expect.

Comment: Your `PrintAll()` has a bug. You have `node* current;` then `while (current != NULL)` Where does node current get a value?

Comment: `while (current != NULL)` what is the value of `current` when you reach this condition? Also inside the loop you dont modify `current`, ie once entered you never leave the loop.

Comment: btw "once entered you never leave the loop" is strictly speaking wrong. Your code has undefined behavior, and thats all one can say for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this declaration in the global namespace

```
struct node
{
    string name;
    int number;
    node* next;
};
struct node* head = 0;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is redundant and is used nowhere. Remove it.

It is better to make the structure node an inner member of the class Employees. For example

```
class Employees
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        string name;
        int number;
        node* next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
    //...
```

The constructor does nothing special. So it can be defined as a default constructor.

```
 Employees() = default;
```

Th function `addToList` should accept the first argument by constant reference

```
void addToList( const string &Name, int Num )
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function `PrintAll` has an infinite loop when the pointer head is not a null pointer

```
void PrintAll()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and moreover it invokes undefined behavior because the used pointer current was not initialized

```
node* current;
while (current != NULL)
```

The function should be declared with the qualifier const because it does not change the list itself.

Also you need a destructor to free the dynamically allocated memory for nodes. Also you could suppress the copy construction and assignment.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the class can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employees
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        string name;
        int number;
        node* next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

public:
    Employees() = default;

    ~Employees()
    {
        while ( head != nullptr )
        {
            node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    Employees( const Employees & ) = delete;
    Employees & operator =( const Employees & ) = delete;

    void addToList( const string &Name, int Num )
    {
        node *n = new node { Name, Num, nullptr };

        if ( head == nullptr )
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = n;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    void PrintAll() const
    {
        for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            cout << current->name << ' ';
            cout << current->number << '\t';
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employees a;
    a.addToList( "Robert", 54 );
    a.addToList( "Manny", 77 );

    a.PrintAll();

    cout << endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
Robert 54   Manny 77
```

Answer (score 2):

You have issue with

1. `PrintAll` where `Head` is unaltered and makes it infinite loop.
2. `current` is uninitialised and accessing it as a pointer is UB

Below snippet shoud fix your problem,

```
void PrintAll()
{
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
       std::cout << temp ->name << "\t";
       std::cout << temp ->number;
       temp = temp->next            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem with your code is that your `PrintAll` method is written incorrectly and you never update your `current` pointer. Perhaps you've not been taught `for` loops yet, but this is an ideal case for them:

```
for(node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
  cout << current->name << "\t" << current->number;
}
```

The first part of the for loop initialises the variable (which you neglected to do in your code), the next is the end condition (as you'd find in a `while` loop), and the third part updates the variable each cycle through the loop thus traversing your loop from start to end.

You can do all this with a `while` loop but it expresses your intent less clearly, so a `for` loop should be preferred. I am also not sure why you have a `while` loop checking whether `head` is null? Since it does not change during the loop, there is no need to repeatedly check it, and - in any case - there is no advantage to checking it separately as opposed to simply checking `current` once it has been initialised to `head`.

As a minor note, if you're using a modern C++ version, `nullptr` should be preferred over `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues:

```
while (head != NULL)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

You do not modify `head` inside the loop (why would you), hence this loop would run either never or forever.

Second:

```
 node* current;
 while (current != NULL)
```

`current` in uninitialized. Comparing it to `NULL` invokes undefined behavior. Always initialize your variables!

Last:

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    cout << current->name << "\t";
    cout << current->number;
}
```

Similar to the first issue, the loop condition is either `true` or `false`, but it never changes, ie the loop either runs never or infinite.

As this appears to be an exercise, I'll leave it to you to fix the code.